# Consuming animals by slaughtering vs injecting barbiturates?

Tags: zoology, pharmacology, hematology

In "[Least painful way to die](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/least-painful-way-to-die)" we get an answer ...

> Companion animals (e.g., dogs and cats): injected barbiturates are recommended
>
> Laboratory animals (e.g., mice and rats): injected barbiturates are acceptable as are inhaled agents (isoflurane, carbon dioxide).

And assume the butcher guy as soon as he comes to know the animal is gone, he will do the following....

> A very sharp knife is used in this process: the point of the knife cuts into the animal's throat and cuts through the dewlap, trachea, esophagus and jugular vein immediately below the jaw-line to allow the blood to flow out.........Animals are bled out before being dressed because it prevents blood from coagulating in the tissues and thus making the meat go rancid. (Source [Slaughter Cattle](http://www.wikihow.com/Slaughter-Cattle) commercial method - Step 6)

Here's my question... What if the animal was killed using 'barbiturates', then is that animal safe for eating by humans or the high levels of 'barbiturates' in that body cause unwanted results in humans too (if they consume it)?

---

I'm new to biology. :)

Comment: even if it is OK, drugs might be too expensive for large-scale food manufacturing

Comment: but at the cost of the pain of animals... suppose if people become merciful enough to spend more bucks to eat a hen... then? @aandreev

Comment: I know for many antibiotics the animal cannot be slaughtered for consumption within a certain time (some can be upwards of 60 days I think). Even NSAIDs like banamine (flunixin) require a brief withdrawal period (1 week if I remember right). I'd imagine barbituates would also require such restrictions.

Comment: "the animal cannot be slaughtered for consumption within a certain time" a little explanation about that and confidence about what you said would make it a good answer in the answer box @canadianer :)

Comment: Sure, I'll check some drug bottles for the actual time frames and post an answer when I get a chance. I really can't say anything about barbiturates though.

Comment: "cost of the pain of animals" does not exist. Only real alternative is free-range meat gunned down in forest,but it is not as tasty

Comment: Barbiturates are narcotics.. they will have even more stringent restrictions compared to NSAIDs and antibiotics.

Comment: It is important to note that farm animals are not protected under the animal welfare act

Comment: so you mean to say the answer is 'no', it is not at all possible.???. @WYSIWYG

Comment: so you mean to say we can play with them anyway we like is it ?? @CactusWoman

Comment: Yes and no. To be more specific, there exists a "common farming practices" exemption in the animal welfare act, meaning a practice that is considered a common farming practice, such as using a knife for slaughter, can be performed legally on farm animals when it would be illegal to perform it on, for instance, a dog. So, it's not that you can do _whatever_ you want to farm animals, but rather you can do any common farming practices to them. It is also important to note, as WYSIWYG said, that barbiturates are narcotics and not necessarily safe for consumption in any case.

Comment: @servantofWiser I think chemicals can be used to numb an animal after which it is killed by regular slaughtering practices. CO₂ and other gases are used to asphyxiate and make the animal unconscious before it is slaughtered. Inhaled anaesthetics may also be fine because they won't be resident in the body for a long time. But I don't think injected anaesthetics and barbiturates would be a good option. Xenon is a safe anaesthetic but is very costly.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort everyone has put in here in helping me sort things out! :)

Comment: Actually, slaughter with a sufficiently sharp knife, and sufficiently skilled butcher, is supposedly nearly painless (e.g. Hebrew/Islam ritual slaughter). Think about how you don't notice a paper cut right away, then imagine that you suddenly pass out from blood loss. The reason knife slaughter is often frowned upon is because large operations tend to start cutting corners on the knife and/or butcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many drugs, the animal cannot be slaughtered for consumption within a certain time. Here are the slaughter withdrawal periods for some common drugs when used on cattle. There are also withdrawal periods for lactating dairy cattle, but I won't list them for brevity.

- flunixin (NSAID) - 6 days
- florfenicol (antibiotic) - 36 days intramuscular, 55 days subcutaneous
- penicillin G procaine (antibiotic) - 10-14 days
- tilmicosin (antibiotic) - 28 days
- oxytetracycline (antibiotic) - 28 days intramuscular, 48 days subcutaneous
- enrofloxacin (antibiotic) - 36 days, do not use in veal calves

More importantly for your question, I have found this [report on pentobarbital used for euthanizing cattle.](http://www.vmd.defra.gov.uk/productinformationdatabase/SPC_Documents/SPC_339773.DOC) It says:

> Adequate measures should be taken to ensure that carcasses of animals treated with this product and the by-products of these animals do not enter the food chain and are not used for human or animal consumption.

Barbiturates are more dangerous than many other drugs and, furthermore, dead animals cannot metabolize them and they can be quite heat stable (ie won't readily decompose during cooking).

Comment: seriously! you answered this? Cool! ......I know a simple 'thanks' is not sufficient, but still, a simple 'thanks'. :)

Comment: @servantofWiser You're welcome.